# How to save response log in variable using rest assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

following is my post re quest , in console i am able to see the log i want to store in variable.:

RestAssured.baseURI = "https://www.dummy.com//services";

```
            RestAssured.given().
            headers("data",crypto). 
        when().
            post("//auth.svc/auth").
        then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).log().all();
```

Comment: What is your response and what would you like to store as a variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().
             headers("data",crypto). 
             when().
             post("//auth.svc/auth").
             then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).
             extract().response();
```

Afterwards you could save the response as a string with `response.asString()` or inspect the json with a JsonPath object. For example:

```
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
jsonPathEvaluator.get("xyz");
```